# Removing layer and redrawing it again in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, mapbox, jquery

I have a geoJSON polygon in my map and I want to update its color after changing the values by getting a JSON value. So I wrote the below code which changes the property value successfully.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([1.3096622448984000, 103.7689017333800], 10);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.light'
    }).addTo(map);
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();




    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return  d > 2000 ? '#000080' :
                d > 100  ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 500  ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 100  ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 50   ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 20   ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 10   ? '#6fdc6f' :
                           '#FFEDA0';

    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#999',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.state1)
        };
    }

    var geojson = L.geoJson(campus, {
        style: style,
    }).addTo(map);

    function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });


    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);

    }
function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
     info.update();
}
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
}


function searchText(e,feature)
{
     var layer = e.target;
     var search = {
            'zone': layer.feature.properties.name,
            'zone_id':layer.feature.id
             };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    url: "http://posturl/",
                    data: JSON.stringify(search), // Note it is important
                    success :function(result) {
                     // do what ever you want with data
                     //  alert("suc");

                   },
                    error:function(error){
                     //alert("success");
                      }
                });
 }


var lastClickedLayer;

function onMapClick(e,feature) {


    var layer = e.target;

    $("#grid_name").html(layer.feature.properties.name);


    searchText(e,feature);





}



function mapupdatecolor(startDate,endDate,e){
     console.log(endDate);
    $.getJSON('http://dataurl', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (i = 0; i <24; i++) { 

            console.log("1 time state1 in console--"+campus['features'][i]['properties']['state1']);
            campus['features'][i]['properties']['state1']=data[i].state1;
            console.log("2 time state1 in console after change--"+campus['features'][i]['properties']['state1']);

        }


     map.removeLayer(geojson);

    var geojson = L.geoJson(campus, {
        style: style,
    }).addTo(map);

    });


}


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {



    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        //click: zoomToFeature
        click:onMapClick

    });

}

geojson = L.geoJson(campus, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};


// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4><b>Zones<b></h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />'  
        : 'Hover over a zone');


};


info.addTo(map);
```

The campus variable will be in another script as

```
var campus = {


        "type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
            {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id":"87",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "CHANGI POINT(SOUTH)",
                            "state1":"10"
                        },
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "MultiPolygon",
                            "coordinates": [
                                [
                                    [
                                        [103.981,1.32749],[103.986,1.32528],[103.986,1.32528],[103.986,1.3251],[103.986,1.32508],[103.99,1.32301],[103.995,1.32166],[104.001,1.32121],[104.005,1.32192],[104.01,1.32296],[104.017,1.32545],[104.026,1.32538],[104.033,1.32558],[104.033,1.31493],[104.031,1.31479],[104.028,1.31473],[104.028,1.31731],[104.028,1.31954],[104.023,1.31957],[104.023,1.31506],[104.019,1.31509],[104.011,1.31456],[104.004,1.31003],[104.001,1.30937],[103.991,1.31284],[103.983,1.31127],[103.983,1.31238],[103.985,1.31369],[103.984,1.31591],[103.982,1.3163],[103.976,1.31493],[103.975,1.31596],[103.976,1.32187],[103.976,1.32439],[103.976,1.32623],[103.976,1.32666],[103.977,1.32676],[103.977,1.32748],[103.978,1.32787],[103.979,1.32797],[103.979,1.32792],[103.981,1.32749]
                                        ]

                                        ]
                            ]
                        }

                    }
```

]};

So I want to remove the layer and redraw it again. I am triggering the mapudatecolor function in the event below (another script)

```
     clickApply: function(e) {
    var startDate = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate._d;
    var endDate = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate._d;

    var start_date = new Date(startDate);
    var end_date=new Date(endDate);
    var start = moment(start_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    var end = moment(end_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");







    mapupdatecolor(start,end);




    this.hide();
    this.element.trigger('apply.daterangepicker', this);

}
```

The state1 properties is updated but the color is only not changing.

```
     1 time state1 in console--100
     2 time state1 in console after change--2137
     1 time state1 in console--9
     2 time state1 in console after change--1951
     1 time state1 in console--30
     2 time state1 in console after change--1592
```

I get the error in

```
fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.state1)
```

**cannot read property properties**

Are these lines correct

```
 map.removeLayer(geojson);

        var geojson = L.geoJson(campus, {
            style: style,
        }).addTo(map);
```

I am new to Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found how to solve

```
map.removeLayer(L.geoJson);

        var geojson = L.geoJson(campus, {
            style: style,
             onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }).addTo(map);
```

It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

`map.removeLayer(L.geoJson);` does not remove the layer

You need to pass the result of that method.

Something like:

```
function addLayer() {
  return L.geoJson(campus, {
            style: style,
             onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }).addTo(map);
}
let layer = addLayer()

function redrawLayer(){
  map.removeLayer(layer)
  layer = addLayer()
}
```

This worked for me.